# How to measure current practically in a circuit

Tags: resistors, measurement, multimeter, kirchhoffs-laws

I have to measure this circuit, I have done the theoretical calculations using Kirchhoff's 2nd law, but I'm having troubles in measuring the current in each part of the circuit:

I have to measure current in I1, I2 and I3 practically, so where I need open the circuit to obtain the current closing the net using a multimeter?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqCNVc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Well, you would need to insert the Ammeter into each branch whose current you want to measure.  The Ammeter must be in series with any other branch components.

Comment: KCL says anywhere, since you need to measure the current in all branches in the circuit. Where you open it determines which branch you're measuring.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I'm able to measure the current, and the most important thing, I can understand it at all!. So thanks again mates!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to open up the circuit at all, if you know you can trust the resistors.

If you measure the voltage across R3 you get a reading proportional to the current by I3 = V3 / R3. Or, put simply, with R3 being 1kOhm, you get 1V for each 1mA through R3.

If you measure across R2 you get a voltage proportional to the current I2, by: I2 = V2 / R2. Or, again simply, with R2 being 2kOhm, you get 2V for each 1mA through R2.

If you measure across R1 you get the current through R1. Verify that the current Through R1 is the current through V1, which is also the current coming out of V1, which is in fact I1.

Answer (score 2):

AM1 measuring I1, AM2 measuring I2 and AM3 measuring I3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ6DIQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you add a GND to the circuit, you can actually run the DC analysis.